# Can’t access to custom canvas attribute in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, aframe

Has anyone used this component with Vue?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-draw-component.

I want to use Advanced Usage with “aframe-draw-component”.
it works with raw html but not vue.js. [codepen example](https://codepen.io/sky790312/pen/PjWJdE)

```
// html
<a-scene fog="type: exponential; color:#000">
  <a-sky acanvas rotation="-5 -10 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>

// js
const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRWXYZ'.split('')
const font_size = 8

AFRAME.registerComponent("acanvas", {
  dependencies: ["draw"],
  init: function(){
    console.log(this.el.components)
    this.draw = this.el.components.draw // get access to the draw component
    this.draw.canvas.width = '512'
    this.draw.canvas.height = '512'
    this.cnvs = this.draw.canvas
    const columns = this.cnvs.width / font_size
    this.drops = []
    for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
      this.drops[x] = 1
    }
    this.ctx = this.draw.ctx
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)'
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.cnvs.width, this.cnvs.height)
    this.ctx.fillStyle = '#0F0'
    this.ctx.font = font_size + 'px helvetica'
    for(let i = 0; i < this.drops.length; i++) {
      const txt = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)]
      this.ctx.fillText(txt, i * font_size, this.drops[i] * font_size)
      if(this.drops[i] * font_size > this.cnvs.height && Math.random() > 0.975) {
        this.drops[i] = 0 // back to the top!
      }
      this.drops[i] = this.drops[i] + 1
    }
    this.draw.render()
  }
})
```

No matter where I put in Vue component, I get this error:

App.vue?b405:124 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property ‘canvas’ of undefined
at NewComponent.init (eval at

It can’t find the custom dependency “draw”.

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried so someone may have a chance to help you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas element is at Your disposal in the el.components.draw.canvas reference.

You can either create Your standalone vue script, or attach it to an existing component like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("vue-draw", {
init: function() {
  const vm = new Vue({
    el: 'a-plane',
    mounted: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var draw = document.querySelector('a-plane').components.draw; /
        var ctx = draw.ctx;
        var canvas = draw.canvas;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(68, 68, 120, 120);
        draw.render();
      }, 100)
    }
  });
}
})
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6bado2q2/2/ 
Basically, I just accessed the canvas, and told it to draw a rectangle.

---

Please keep in mind, that Your error may persist when You try to access the canvas before the draw component managed to create it.

---

My no-brainer solution was just a timeout. Since the scene loads, and starts rendering faster, than the canvas is being made, I would suggest making a interval checking if the canvas element is defined somehow, and then fire the vue.js script.

---

Also keep in mind, that You can work on existing canvas elements with the build in canvas texture: https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/material.html

Comment: I found that my problem now is I don't know how to use aframe-draw-component with advaned usage. When I import aframe, aframe-draw-component in Vue file, I check the AFRAME in console. I can't find draw in components.

Comment: could you give me some example in codepen inside vue template ? Thanks.

Comment: @KevinHu 1. You want to find it in the 'elements' tab in the console ? or in the aframe inspector ? 2. by vue template, You mean this one: https://codepen.io/cheapsteak/pen/dGXZjx?editors=101 linked at a-frame-extras ?

Comment: yes, like your example. I can use A-frame in vue template, but I want to use aframe-draw-component's registerComponent like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-draw-component
But after I import this, I can't find the draw components in AFRAME.
Can you use aframe-draw-component in your example ?
https://github.com/maxkrieger/aframe-draw-component/issues/7